# UIAlert is getting dismissed immediately after being presented. Swift

Tags: swift3

I am trying to present "UIAlert" If Username and Password is nil.  When I tap on register button with out filling the details, It is showing an Alert. It is fine. But Alert is dismissing immediately after being presented. It is not letting me to tap on OK. Here is my code. any help is appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var newUserNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var newPasswordField: UITextField!
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var registeredUsers = [String]()
    var passwordArr = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func registerButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if (newUserNameField.text == "") && (newPasswordField.text == "")  {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops", message: "All fields must not be left blank when proceeding!", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        if defaults.object(forKey: "usernames") != nil {
            registeredUsers = defaults.array(forKey: "usernames") as! [String]
            passwordArr = defaults.array(forKey: "passwords") as! [String]
        }

    // create a new account
        registeredUsers.insert(newUserNameField.text!, at: registeredUsers.count)
        passwordArr.insert(newPasswordField.text!, at: passwordArr.count)
        defaults.set(registeredUsers, forKey: "usernames")
        defaults.set(passwordArr, forKey: "passwords")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are presenting and at the same time dismissing, that leads to the issue.

Remove this line

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You have make multiple mistakes .

- suppose your textfields are empty the alert will show and other line of code be executed, which should NOT be.
  So you should be use *return statement* so that when user gets error, so not required code will never be executed.
- and in the last line you have **dismiss the alert** which should **not be there . So you have to remove that line of code**